# Excel - reference to XLAM file not being saved

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get references to an XLAM file to be saved with a spreadsheet. I have to add the reference every time I open the spreadsheet.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new workbook.
2. Go to the VBA editor and rename the VBA project to "MyAdvancedMath".
3. Add a module. Name it "AdvancedMath".
4. Add the following VBA in "AdvancedMath":

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Add(A As Double, B As Double) As Double
    Add = A + B
End Function
```

5. Close the VBA editor. Save the file, changing the type to "Excel Add-in (*.xlam)". Let it save to the default folder ("C:\Users<>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns"). I called it "MyAdvMathAddIn.xlam".
6. Close all copies of Excel.
7. Start Excel. Create a new workbook. Save it as a macro-enabled workbook. I called it "MyAdvMathTest.xlsm".
8. Go to the VBA editor. Then go to Tools - References. Browse and add a reference to "MyAdvMathAddIn.xlam".
9. Set the formula in cell A1 to

=Add(4,8)

You should see the value 12 in cell A1.

10. Save "MyAdvMathTest.xlsm" and close it.
11. Open "MyAdvMathTest.xlsm". Cell A1 still has the value 12, as it should. Put the cursor in cell A1 and press Enter. Excel complains with a "#NAME?" error because it can't find the "Add" function.
12. Go to the VBA editor and re-add the reference.
13. Put the cursor in cell A1 and then press Enter. Now you see the value 12 again.

I'm running Microsoft 365 Apps for business, version 2209 (build 15629.20156 click-to-run). x64 version on x64 Windows 10.

The AddIns folder has been added to Trusted Locations. The Trust Center Macro Settings & ActiveX Settings are as permissive as they can possibly be, so it doesn't seem to be a security issue.

Note that the .xlam file must be referenced only from certain spreadsheets. Not all spreadsheets used by my employer.

Also note that this question was posted on Microsoft Answers (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-reference-to-xlam-file-not-being-saved/f62b4764-1b27-4afb-a920-2e6804f8b213). The moderator suggested that I post here.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: In "MyAdvMathTest.xlsm", create a module and create any sub or function, it doesn't have to do anything and doesn't have to be public. Excel removes all custom references if there isn't at least one sub or function in the workbook... its dumb.

Comment: @Toddleson You nailed it. Works now. Thank you!